# How should I wire this 2-way light switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, uk

I am replacing both of the hallway light switches in my house in the UK, and upon taking off the old switches, I am met with the following cable configuration:

[image: Setup]

Downstairs is a 2-gang switch that controls both the downstairs hall light, and the upstairs hall light. I know which wires control the downstairs light and can successfully wire it in.

Upstairs, there are 2 sets of 3 wires coming in, one with a red sleeve on the black wire, and one with the black wire disconnected and covered with electrical tape.

Inside the [back box](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41wIhoY-xXL.jpg) of the switch downstairs, there was also an extra piece of brown cable, but I don't know what it was connected to.

How should I connect these wires to a 2-way switch for the upstairs light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself with a live wire detector:

[image]

I believe the red/black on the far right of the diagram are wired incorrectly, as the black is live and the red neutral.

I believe this set up is described [here](http://www.lightwiring.co.uk/two-way-switching-two-wire-control/), which states that it's not recommended for new installations for many reasons, but can be found in old homes.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the far right red wire is switched-live, and the far right black wire is *probably* unused. But you'd have to find the other end to confirm. There is no neutral in the light switch with this old-style configuration, just lives and switched-lives (and potentially unused wires).